Question about aptitude
I tried to run
$sudo apt install aptitude
Then it returns this
Package 'aptitude' has no installation candidate
Please

What does this mean
What can I do about it


Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

The aptitude package is provided in the Ubuntu "universe" repository - see How do I enable the "Universe" repository?
